# Positioning and Sizing JScrollBar on a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jdialog

I am having trouble getting my scroll bar to work with my JDialog. I am obviously not adding the scroll bar properly but I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.

**Clarification update**

```
timeLineDialog = new JDialog();
scroller=new JScrollPane();
scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
timeLineDialog.setLayout(layout);
timeLineDialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.MODELESS);
timeLineDialog.setTitle("Time Line Settings");
timeLineDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
timeLineDialog.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1004,400));

// all my components are added to the JDialog here
// I use GridBagLayout to essentially create rows of components
```

timeLineDialog.add(...);

```
timeLineDialog.add(scroller);
timeLineDialog.pack();
timeLineDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(GUI.getInstance().getFrame());
timeLineDialog.setVisible(true);
```

While I get the scroll bar it is small and is placed only at the end of the 3rd row.

[image]

It never really scrolls anything and as I add rows the layout manager simply makes things smaller to get it to fit and the buttons at the bottom begin to move off the pane. What am I doing wrong? TIA.

Comment: If you need more help post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. This is easily done by create a panel. Then you create a loop that adds 20/30 JButtons (or any other component) to the panel. Then you create a JScrollPane using the panel as a parameter. Then you add the panel to the frame. It should take about 20-30 lines of code for the simple demo. Then if it doesn't work you have something simply to post in the forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> // all my components are added to the JDialog here
>   // I use GridBagLayout to essentially create rows of components

You never add any component to the JScrollPane.

The code should be:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
panel.add(...);
panel.add(...);

//scroller=new JScrollPane();
scroller=new JScrollPane(panel);
...
//timeLineDialog.getContentPane().add(scroller);
timeLineDialog().add(scroller);
```

Note, there is no need for the `getContentPane()` method, the component will automatically be added to the content pane.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear, the components were added to the JDialog not the JScrollPane. I see you are using JPanel in your example rather than JDialog. Is that a significant distinction? I've updated the OP.

Comment: `I was not clear, the components were added to the JDialog not the JScrollPane.` - yes you were clear and that is the problem. You can't add the components directly to the dialog if you want then to scroll . You add the component to a panel, the panel to the scroll pane and the scrollpane to the dialog. There is a parent/child relationship between dialog, scrollpane, panel, components.

Comment: @WtRiker You were given this same answer when you asked this question a week ago. Don't forget to start "accepting" answers by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: I didn't "accept" that answer because it didn't look to me like it would help without a rewrite. Perhaps I did not show enough code but I was not extending the JDialog class in my code. I also asked additional questions that were never answered so I abandoned that thread as stale. I did manage to get a scroll bar to show up, such as it is, so I thought I was on the right track and I started this new thread. You added some critical information here that was missing (or at least not obvious to me as a requirement) before, namely the need for the addition of a JPanel. I'll give that a try. Thanks

Comment: `it didn't look to me like it would help without a rewrite.` - if the structure of your code is wrong then you need to do a rewrite to fix it. That is not a reason to not accept an answer.

Comment: That presupposes I know my structure is unsalvagably wrong. As far as I knew at the time tell it was not. Since you are telling me it is, I think I am struggling with the hierarchy of the parent/child relationship. The JDialog and JScrollPane are added to the panel so when the JDialog gets bigger than the JPanel preferred size the scroll bar pops up, right?

Comment: `That presupposes I know my structure is unsalvagably wrong.` - you asked a question and were told it was wrong. So the solution is to listen to the suggestion given and try it! That is the point of a question/answer forum. If we can take the time to answer a question, the least you can do is take the time to try the suggestion. `The JDialog and JScrollPane are added to the panel` - I specifically stated: **You add the component to a panel, the panel to the scroll pane and the scrollpane to the dialog.** I also gave code showing how to do that. I don't know how to be any clearer than that?

Comment: See [Using Top Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html). for some Swing basics. You can also check out `How to Use Text Areas` for an example using a scrollpane. The only difference is a text area is a single component, but you want to scroll a panel containing multiple components, so you add the panel to the scrollpane.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully I have it now. It was changing the JDialog to a Panel that was throwing me. Having 'dialog' in the class name made me think that was where the interactive components HAD to go. Also I need to retrieve the components and JPanel does not have that method. It will take some research to figure out how to conver to JPanel.

Comment: `Thanks. Hopefully I have it now.` and yet the answer still hasn't been "accepted". `It will take some research to figure out how to conver to JPanel.` - it will take no research. You just add the components to the panel and the panel to the dialog.  I gave you 5 lines of code to demonstrate the concept of add components to a panel and the panel to a dialog. I don't understand what you find so confusing about this given all the answers you have received and the code you can look at from the tutorials. What happened when you tried it with 2 or 3 components???